# ¿Alguna forma de poder reutilizar un checkbox/input sin recargar la página? .prop() y checked=false; los dejan inutilizables

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, checkbox

Tengo un formulario de crear publicación donde hay checkboxs y inputs del tipo radio. Al enviar el formulario, se le da la opción al  usuario de volver a crear otras publicaciones simplemente volviendo a hacer click en la misma opción de publicar sin tener que recargar la página. Para esto, al enviar la publicación, reseteo todos los input para que salgan vacíos y disponibles para llenarlos nuevamente con

```
$('.modal-dialog').find('input, textarea').val('');
```

Con los checkbox y los input hago lo siguiente:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', false);
```

El problema es que, si luego el usuario en su nueva publicación vuelve a checkearlos, se envían vacíos, como si no los hubieran seleccionado.
Probé también con:

```
var allInp = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(i = 0; i < allInp.length; i++){
  if (allInp[i].type == 'radio' || allInp[i].type == 'checkbox'){
     allInp[i].checked = false;
 }
}
```

Pero el problema es el mismo. Cumplen su función de destildar todo lo seleccionado. Pero me deja los input radio y checkbox inutilizables para volver a seleccionarlos nuevamente.

¿Hay alguna forma de destildarlos todos, pero que queden disponibles para volver a ser seleccionados si el usuario así lo desea?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Creo que la pregunta es buena, pero debe reformularse un poco el título. No la edito porque no domino el tema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en la línea en la que haces:

`$('.modal-dialog').find('input, textarea').val('')`

Le estás vaciando el valor incluso a los `<input type="checkbox">` y a los `<input type="radio">` y un input de estos tipos que no tenga valor, no se envía.

Tienes que controlarlo con algo como esto:

```js
$(function () {
  const input = $('input, textarea')
  
  input.each(function () {
    const elemento = $(this)
    
    if (elemento.is('[type="checkbox"]') || elemento.is('[type="radio"]')) {
      elemento.prop('checket', false)
    }
    else {
      elemento.val('')
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" value="1">
<input type="radio" value="2">
<input type="text" value="Hola">
<input type="number" value="3">
<textarea value="Hola como estás"></textarea>
```

De esta manera a los input que son tipo radio o checkbox se les cambia la propiedad checked a false y a los que son de cualquier otro tipo (incluidos los textarea) se les vacía el valor.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Me había enfocado en que el problema era por el .prop(), y no se me pasó por la cabeza que podía ser por la anterior línea.